# How to turn off Network Discovery and Share between computers on LAN in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: lan, network-bridge, network-monitoring, network-bonding

I want to disable my Network Discovery and Share between computers on LAN in ubuntu 16.04 LTS .
Please help in terms of terminal coding or may be another way.

Comment: **is** there  _anyone_ to  answer this question .

Comment: Is there any problem in question?

Comment: Maybe if you specify what Network Discovery and Share you see, somebody might answer. Have you configured NFS or SAMBA shares or what is the "problem" ?